# TCL Flush Ignore Backspace

Tags: tcl, user-input, flush

Is there a way to ignore backspaces when performing a flush in tcl to capture user input?

I am performing a function where I capture the user input in a variable to be used in another command at a later time. So I perform the following function.

```
puts -nonewline "What is the username? "
flush stdout
set usrnm [gets stdin]
```

So let's say using that command as long as I don't use a backspace everything works the way I expect it however if I do use a backspace a "\x7F" is added as a character. Is there a way for the backspace to not be treated as a character?

Comment: It seems your terminal isn't in a cooked mode , please see http://wiki.tcl.tk/11866

Answer (score 0):

That seems to depend on your terminal; when I try that code with these key sequences:

- <kbd>Backspace</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>
- <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>

Then I get a length 3 string (measured via `string length`) in the `usrnm` variable in both cases. This is what I'd expect when the terminal is properly in cooked mode (the usual default). Since a `\x7f` is probably not a valid character in a user name anyway, I'd guess that you could filter it out:

```
set usrnm [string map {\x7f ""} $usrnm]
```

The only way to be *absolutely* sure that the character isn't there is to put the terminal in to raw mode (and probably no-echo too) and do all the character input processing yourself. That's a huge amount of work relative to the size of problem; a post-filter seems more sensible to me (and I still wonder what's up with your terminal).

---

[EDIT]: To put your terminal back into cooked mode, do:

```
exec stty -raw <@stdin
```

Comment: Okay that would fix that problem but at the same time I would like the backspace function to work like it should and remove the undesired character.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but the exec stty -raw <@stdin does not work. I am using the TCL interpreter on Cisco IOS.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this recently and I wrote a procedure to handle the char 127 character (backspace).  If any other input cleansing needs to happen you can do it here too, such as removing special characters.  I have a feeling this can be more elegant but it does work.

```
proc cleanInput {str} {
    set return ""
    for {set i 0} {$i < [string length $str]} {incr i} {
        set char [string index $str $i]
        set asc [scan $char %c]
        if {$asc == 127} { #backspace
            if {[string length $return] > 0} {
                set return [string range $return 0 [expr "[string length $return] - 2"]]
            }
        } else {
            append return $char
        }
    }
    return $return
}
```